# How to use the length attribute in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am currently learning to build a shopping app and working on the cart functionality of the react native application. I have made a separate shopping cart icon component which I am passing into the main application. However, when I try to display the number of items in the shopping cart icon using the length attribute, the length is not getting displayed. I am a beginner and any help will be appreciated.

ShoppingCartIcon.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Picker,Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

goToNextScreen = () => {
  Actions.cartScreen();
}

const ShoppingCartIcon = (props) => (

      <View style={{position:'absolute', top:0,left:0,width: 40,height: 40,borderRadius: 40/2,paddingTop:3}}>
           <View style={{
          position: 'absolute', height: 20, width: 20, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: 'rgba(6,21,42,0.8)', top:0, left: 5, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', zIndex: 2000

                  }}>
                  <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold',fontSize:10 }}>{props.cartItems.length}</Text>
            </View>
          <Icon onPress={() => this.goToNextScreen()} name="shopping-cart"  style ={{fontSize:30, position:'absolute', top:0,padding:7, left:0, color:'#fe003a'}} />
      </View>
)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        cartItems: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ShoppingCartIcon);
```

Output:

[The image of the shopping cart icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Okm.jpg)

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(props)`?

Comment: How are you sending props to shopping cart icon? please elaborate further.

Comment: @Tim console.log(props) displays all the properties of the app. Console.log(prop.cartItems.length) displays undefined.

Comment: @AnusKaleem I am sending props to shopping cart icon using reducers.

Comment: I suspect there is some wrong in data you are sending through reducer. Can you share the data being sent? Or you can just console log  what’s coming in “cartItmes” to get a more clear picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `mapStateToProps` function, you set `cartItems: state`, but maybe you'd have to do `cartItems: state.YourReducerName.yourArrayName`. Could you post the reducer code as well?